# Cannot Delete GRE Tunnel

Tags: linux, tunneling, gre

I am configuring a GRE tunnel in Linux 2.6.26 and I've been facing a very strange problem for which I could not find any solution.

I have created a GRE tunnel called `gre0`, but no matter what I do, I am simply unable to delete this tunnel. The command `ip tunnel del gre0` fails with the response `ioctl: Operation not permitted`. Any attempt to change the addresses of the tunnel also fails.

The following commands illustrate the problem:

```
# ip tunnel del gre0
ioctl: Operation not permitted
# ip tunnel change gre0
# ip tunnel change gre0 remote <some address> local <some address>
ioctl: No such file or directory
```

I can create, change and delete other tunnels without any problem, but `gre0` just sticks there and does not go away, even if I reboot or take the interfaces down.

If I remove the `ip_gre` module, the tunnel disappears. As soon as I insert the module again, `gre0` reappears and the problem continues.

I have two questions:

1. What can I do to get rid of this pesky tunnel? I suspect this might be a kernel or a module bug.
2. Where such persistent data (in this case, the information for `gre0`, but this applies to any other setup I may be even unaware of) is stored?

If any other information is needed, please let me know.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `gre0` tunnel interface is named as the fallback interface and has special meaning. It's created by `ip_gre` kernel module at initialization of module. You cannot disable this feature.

When the host receives gre packets for which the suitable tunnel interface isn't found, this fallback interface will be used. Unfortunately, it's really undocumented feature. Only in [the source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/ipv4/ip_tunnel.c#L72) this is described.

Same logic is used for other types of tunneling.

So you cannot remove it completely without lost of other gre tunnels. But you can rename it with command `ip link set dev gre0 name gre_fallback`. And then you can create the other gre tunnel with `gre0` name.

Comment: After eight years, the correct answer appears. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

I believe I've found myself an answer to this problem.

After tinkering for a while, I decided to reproduce the problem in a clean installation.

The `ip_gre` module is not inserted by default in the kernel after installing Debian. `ip tunnel show` does not display any tunnel. After inserting the `ip_gre` module, but without creating any tunnel, `gre0` appears and is undeletable and unchangeable as expected. Thus `gre0` seems to be a dummy tunnel created by default by the `ip_gre` module.

The frustrating part is that this 'feature' is totally undocumented, and is even an unexpected one, since it might be natural to attempt to create a `gre0` tunnel as the first (and only) GRE tunnel in a system.

Comment: This is also true for tunl0 and sit0.

Comment: And, for `tunl0`, it's `ipip` instead.

Comment: Although you can't delete the dummy interfaces, you can rename them. `ip link set dev $oldname name $newname` (`dev` is optional but disambiguates when you have an interface name that would otherwise be recognized as an option by `ip`). Whilst this doesn't answer the question as posed, it might be useful in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

You need to verify that the gre module is completely removed. Run

```
sudo lsmod | grep gre
```

to check if the module is in the list. If it is, run

```
sudo rmmod ip_gre
sudo rmmod gre
```

to remove them from the kernel.